# How can I find the date that is 1 day later than another date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

How can I find the next day's date after a given date.

For example, I have a date `2011-11-31`.  How can I get the next date (`2011-12-01`) using PHP?

Similarly, how would I get the previous day's date?

Comment: What do you define "next date" as? The following day?

Comment: yes the next date means 2011-12-01 that is following date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$nextdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($olddate." +1 day"));
```

Comment: like this how can i get previous date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strtotime() function in php:
$date="2011-11-11";
$nextdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " +1 day")); 
echo $nextdate;

It will echo as "2011-11-12".

Similarly to find the previous date use:
$nextdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " -1 day"));

It will echo as "2011-11-10".